# Setting up a WLAN usb stick

Tags: rhel, wifi, usb, wlan, oracle-linux

I'm trying to make the WLAN USB stick connect to a wireless network.

There was an official Linux driver available for download (v4.0.2_9000.20130911, which supports my Linux kernel version) and I used `wifi-radar`

Both had no success in making it work. Probably the driver is not compatible with my Oracle Linux (based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6)

```
# lsusb | grep WLAN
Bus 002 Device 017: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

The problem is that the device still can't be detected even after the driver installation runs to the end. I don't know how to check if it was actually installed, or where it is mounted.

```
# cd RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911
# make
(no errors)
# make install
(no errors)
# /sbin/modprobe 8192cu
# ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: unknown interface: No such device
# /sbin/iwconfig
virbr0-nic no wireless extensions.
eth0       no wireless extensions.
eth1       no wireless extensions.
virbr0     no wireless extensions.
lo         no wireless extensions.
```

Is it possible to somehow specify it manally in `wifi-radar` or what steps should I take?

Comment: Here is a guide for a related device, but with different firmware: http://blog.secaserver.com/2012/05/centos-install-tp-link-tl-wn821n-wireless-usb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After plugging the USB in and out and running the updated script again I made it work. I also ran the `install.sh` script provided with the driver, but it seems that was not needed. Here is my setup:

```
# cd RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911
# make
(no errors)
# make install
(no errors)
# /sbin/modprobe 8192cu
# /sbin/iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"KDG-44A11"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: DC:53:7C:A4:4A:16
          Bit Rate:300 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=73/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
eth1      no wireless extensions.
virbr0    no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to look for any installed wireless device, the command `iwconfig` will list all available devices on your machine. The device may not be called wlan0, however.

If you only see "no wireless extensions" then the installation of your driver failed, or you did not load the driver's kernel module properly.

Comment: [`iwconfig` is deprecated](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/): use `iw` or `ip` instead...

Comment: these commands didn't show the `wlan0` interface so it seems not installed, check updated description